# Is it possible to get a list of strings from a regex?

Tags: regex

Is there a Linux command or software library that returns a list of strings matching a regex it is given as input?

For example, `\d` would return `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, and `9`.

Given that regexes are already quite power-consuming I'd be really suprised if this was the case. Still, if such a solution does not exist, what alternatives are there?

Comment: And a dot should return ALL characters except newline? No, such function does not exist.

Comment: What about the output for `.*`? Infinite number of elements in an array?

Comment: Any regex or just a character class?

Comment: You could write one, but as pointed out, the answer may be infinite. You could write a generator in some languages and call it to produce as many matches as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a python parsing module is an option, there is a pyparsing script to [expand a regular expression into "all" possible matching strings](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/invRegex.py).

Using its `invert(regex)` function, the code

```
for text in invert('\d'):
    print(text)
```

will have the output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```